# Error configuring hibernate with ApplicationContext.xml

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jakarta-ee, configuration

I have troubles configuring Hibernate with Spring's propertiesPlaceholderConfigurer. I have a file, db.properties, which contains key-value pairs with db settings. Now I need to make a configuration of Hibernate within Spring's applicationContext.xml file.

But I keep getting an error, saying:

```
javax.faces.el.EvaluationException: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:102)
    at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:315)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:790)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1282)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:81)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:198)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:646)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.myfaces.webapp.filter.ExtensionsFilter.doFilter(ExtensionsFilter.java:374)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:936)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1004)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at com.dataart.mediaportal.db.HibernateUtil.buildSessionFactory(HibernateUtil.java:15)
    at com.dataart.mediaportal.db.HibernateUtil.<clinit>(HibernateUtil.java:8)
    at com.dataart.mediaportal.dao.impl.UserDAOImpl.login(UserDAOImpl.java:45)
    at com.dataart.mediaportal.controller.bean.LoginBean.authorize(LoginBean.java:42)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:278)
    at org.apache.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:274)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:105)
    at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:87)
    ... 27 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Hibernate Dialect must be explicitly set
    at org.hibernate.dialect.DialectFactory.determineDialect(DialectFactory.java:57)
    at org.hibernate.dialect.DialectFactory.buildDialect(DialectFactory.java:39)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory.determineDialect(SettingsFactory.java:409)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory.buildSettings(SettingsFactory.java:119)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSettings(Configuration.java:2006)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1289)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration.buildSessionFactory(AnnotationConfiguration.java:915)
    at com.dataart.mediaportal.db.HibernateUtil.buildSessionFactory(HibernateUtil.java:12)
    ... 38 more
```

Here is my applicationContext.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="windows-1252"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:lang="http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang"
       xmlns:osgi="http://www.springframework.org/schema/osgi"
       xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
       xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"

       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.2.xsd
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang/spring-lang-3.2.xsd
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/osgi http://www.springframework.org/schema/osgi/spring-osgi-1.2.xsd
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.2.xsd
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-3.2.xsd
">

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.dataart.mediaportal" />

<!-- DATA SOURCE AND PERSISTENCE SETTINGS-->
    <bean id="propertiesPlaceholderConfigurer" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
        <property name="locations">
            <list>
                <value>classpath:db.properties</value>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dmDataSource"/>
        <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.dataart.mediaportal"/>
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${db.dialect}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">${db.show_sql}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.import_files">${db.import_files}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">${db.hbm2ddl_auto}</prop>
                <prop key="connection.pool_size">${db.pool_size}</prop>
                <prop key="current_session_context_class">${db.current_session_context_class}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.cache.provider_class">${db.provider_class}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache">${db.use_second_level_cache}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache">${db.use_query_cache}</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="tm" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="dmDataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource" destroy-method="close">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="${db.driver}" />
        <property name="url" value="${db.url}" />
        <property name="username" value="${db.username}" />
        <property name="password" value="${db.password}" />
        <property name="maxActive" value="5" />
        <property name="maxWait" value="5000" />
    </bean>

</beans>
```

[image: Folder's structure. Maybe this will clear the situation.]

db.properies:

```
db.username=postgres
db.password=4351
db.driver=org.postgresql.Driver
db.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost/MediaPortalDB
db.pool_size=1
db.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
db.import_files=import.sql
db.hbm2ddl_auto=create
db.use_query_cache=true
db.use_second_level_cache=true
db.provider_class=org.hibernate.cache.HashtableCacheProvider
db.show_sql=true
db.current_session_context_class=thread
```

I would really appreciate if someone could point me to the solution or tell me what can be wrong here.

Thanks in advance.

Nazar.

Answer (score 1):

Since root cause of error:

> org.hibernate.HibernateException: Hibernate Dialect must be explicitly
>   set

Seems like you are not defining `dialect` in properties file correctly, it is mandatory property.

How are you configuring session factory (not shown in your code) ? You need to call `configure()` before `buildSessionFactory` is called, for example:

To load default hibernate.cfg.xml:

```
new AnnotationConfiguration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
```

To load specific configurations:

```
new AnnotationConfiguration().configure("hibernate-specific.cfg.xml")..buildSessionFactory();
```

Comment: Even if I explicitly assign value to hibernate dialect like this:
<property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect</property>
I keep getting the same error. I quess my applicationContext isn't executed at all.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you're missing a dialect:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Hibernate Dialect must be explicitly set
```

adding this might help:

```
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">
                org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect //add your specific dialect
            </prop>
```

It's one of the hibernate properties.

```
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${db.dialect}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">${db.show_sql}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.import_files">${db.import_files}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">${db.hbm2ddl_auto}</prop>
            <prop key="connection.pool_size">${db.pool_size}</prop>
            <prop key="current_session_context_class">${db.current_session_context_class}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.cache.provider_class">${db.provider_class}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache">${db.use_second_level_cache}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache">${db.use_query_cache}</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
```

put this into your properties:

```
db.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
```

How to load properties file:

```
<bean id="propertyConfigurer"
      class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer"
      p:location="/WEB-INF/connection.properties" />
```

An example of session factory:

```
<bean id="XXX" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean"
      p:dataSource-ref="XXX" >
    <property name="annotatedClasses">
        <list>
            <value>XXX</value>
        </list>    
    </property>
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">
                XXX
            </prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">false</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>
```

This is important part of the session factory declaration:

```
AnnotationSessionFactoryBean
```

Comment: Even if I explicitly assign value to hibernate dialect like this:
<property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect</property>
I keep getting the same error. I quess my applicationContext isn't executed at all.

Comment: I've edited my answer just to make sure you've set up the hibernate properties correctly. Are you still receiving the same error?

Comment: Yup. Nothing changed when I pasted your code into my app. Guess there's some other reason.

Comment: Actually I think your properties aren't loaded properly or you're missing the dialect in them. I've edited my answer again accordingly.

Comment: I've edited my post. There you can view my db.properties file.

Comment: Are you still receiving the same error? If so, try moving the dialect property in your hibernateProperties to the bottom of the property list. If the error changes you got a classpath problem and your properties are not loaded correctly. Otherwise I can't see any problems in your code. I've also added an example how to load properties file.

Comment: Still there's the same error. I have another idea of why this could be happening: maybe something's wrong with the code, which creates the SessionFactory? 
return new AnnotationConfiguration().buildSessionFactory();

Comment: I've added an example of a session factory marking ids and values with XXX where you should have your own values.

Comment: Nothing's changed. =\

Comment: Is the db connection working? This actually might be fake error which is thrown when the db connection fails. Also make sure you're using AnnotationSessionFactoryBean when you're declaring your sessionFactory. (see above)

Comment: The DB connection is ok. Configuration was previously held in the hibernate.cfg.xml file and worked. Implementing the AnnotationSessionFactoryBean didn't help. :(

Comment: Is it possible that you're using more than one hibernate configuration file?

Comment: No, there's only one configuration file. Right now I'm waiting for the results from my mentor. He is checking my code atm.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was hidden in the other place. My application (Facelets / Managed Beans) wasn't managed by Spring at all. After adding next lines to web.xml, all worked:

```
<application>
        <el-resolver>
            org.springframework.web.jsf.el.SpringBeanFacesELResolver
        </el-resolver>
</application>
```

If you are using Servlets/JSP - add DispatcherServlet instead:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>example</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>example</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.form</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Hope this would help someone someday.